# Remove ".200.300." from string

Tags: sed, cut

What's the best way to take a string such as:

```
100.200.300.400
```

And remove the ".200.300." portion of the string leaving "100400".?

UPDATE: Adding some additional context. :) We use Jamf Pro to patch apps on macOS. We use Extension Attributes (EAs) to determine if a computer is in desired state (has the version we are deploying or later). Currently we use multiple EAs, which is not very efficient. Using Adobe Flash Player as an example, the version is always NN.0.0.NNN format. If we remove ".0.0." from the version string, we can have an integer to perform an "-ge" analysis. The end result is we would know if computer is in desired state (app is at desired version or later), or not in desired state (needs update), or not installed (nothing to do). Here is an example of a script I used, using the input from you guys:

```
#!/bin/sh

plistFile="/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin/Contents/version.plist"
versionString=$( defaults read "$plistFile" CFBundleShortVersionString )
currentState=$( echo "${versionString}" | sed 's/\..*\.//' )
desiredState="32114"

if [ -e "$plistFile" ]
then
    if [[ "${currentInteger}" -ge "${desiredInteger}" ]]
    then
        echo "<result>DesiredState</result>"
    else
        echo "<result>NeedsUpdate</result>"
    fi
else
    echo "<result>NotInstalled</result>"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Could you please show a bit more context and what you've tried so far?

Comment: We are pulling a "NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN" string and need to remove ".NNN.NNN.NNN" from the string, to merge the first NNN and last NNN into a single integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "100.200.300.400" | sed 's/\..*\.//'
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! This also worked, not sure which is better":

`| sed 's/.200.300.//g'`

Comment: @donmontalvo, thing is if you use mine it uses regex to remove everything from `.` to another last occurence `.` but yours is very specific one which will remove only that specific string. You could use as per your need.

Comment: Good point, thanks for your input. I updated the original post with more context. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @donmontalvo, not clear. Please explain it more in simple way.